# Xor function from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

can some one help me with this?
I want to convert this CSharp function to VB.

Function in CSharp:

```
public static string XOR(string key, string input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            sb.Append((char)(input[i] ^ key[(i % key.Length)]));
        String result = sb.ToString();

        return result;
    }
```

What I have in VB:

```
Public Function XOR(Key As String, Input As String) As String
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    For i As Integer = 0 To Input.Length - 1
        sb.Append(Chr(Asc(Input(i))) ... )
    Next

    Dim Result As String = sb.ToString()
    Return Result
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Xor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/xor-operator

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is not working? You could just `return SB.ToString` but that is trivial semantics and you may want to do other things with `Result` before returning it. In VB, be aware of the difference between `ByRef` and `ByVal` in your parameters - but that doesn't appear to be an issue in the code above.

Comment: you can just google "c# to vb.net". Seems fine with https://www.mindfusion.eu/convert-cs-vb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you were able to write a function called `XOR` because that's a keyword in VB.NET. You'll have to escape the name as follows: `[XOR]` to have a method with that name.

To do your Xor operation, you just need the built in VB.NET `Xor` operator. Consider the following code.

```
For i = 0 To Input.Length - 1
    sb.Append(ChrW(AscW(input(i)) Xor AscW(key(i Mod key.Length))))
Next
```

Comment: Exactly, you should call it something else like `ExclusiveOr` or escape the name in square brackets.

Comment: And thank you, but with this I got "Xor is not defined for Char and Char".

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the code. I'll review it again

Comment: Thank you, finally it work with my from C# converted PackH function.

Comment: Kudos for noticing that you need ChrW & AscW instead of Chr & Asc.